# Generate new column for a time series with a threshold

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, jupyter-notebook

i'm just starting with this python.
I have a TS data set that look like this:
**IN:**
**adata.head()**
**Out:**

```
datetime    wgt_gain
2018-05-08 16:00:00     0.0
2018-05-08 17:00:00     0.0
2018-05-08 18:00:00     0.0
2018-05-08 19:00:00     0.0
2018-05-08 20:00:00     0.0
```

The description of it is:
**IN: adata.head()**
**Out:**

```
    wgt_gain
count   4227.000000
mean    0.003929
std     0.177180
min     -0.966667
25%     -0.066667
50%     0.000000
75%     0.050000
max     0.985000
```

I would like to apply a new column with a threshold similar to this:
Values:
between 0 and 25% --> 1
between 25% and 50% --> 2
...
between 75% and 100% --> 4
and similar to negative values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html) to bin your values into discrete intervals, with the bins set as the [quantiles](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) you want:

```
adata['new_column'] = (pd.cut(adata.weight_gain,
                              bins = adata.wgt_gain.quantile([0,.25,.5,.75,1]),
                              labels=[1,2,3,4]))
```